# How to pattern match on Proxy?

Tags: haskell

I need a method to conditionally apply a function depending on the specific instance of a class.

I tried using Proxy to annotate the function with the type of its input:

```
class ApplyIf b where
  applyIf :: Show b => proxy a -> (a -> a) -> b -> String

instance ApplyIf Int where
  applyIf (p :: Proxy Int) f b = show (f b)
  applyIf _                _ b = show b

instance ApplyIf String where
  applyIf _ _ b = show b

main = do
  putStrLn $ applyIf (Proxy:: Proxy Int) (*2) 1    -- 2
  putStrLn $ applyIf (Proxy:: Proxy Int) (*2) "ok" -- ok
```

But I get an 'Illegal type signature: 'Proxy Int' error on line 5.

Should I use some other mechanisms, like Tagged, Typeable, ... ?

Comment: To put that type signature you need `ScopedTypeVariables`. `Proxy Int` in the instance decl is more specific than expected from the instance head. try `applyIf (p :: proxy Int) f b = ...`.

Comment: Are you trying to pattern match on the type? It's pretty hard to see from this code fragment what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: `applyIf (Proxy:: Proxy Int) (*2) "ok"` shouldn't typecheck because `b` is `String` and `(*2)` doesn't return a `String`.

Comment: I need to replace (a -> b) by (a ->a) in the class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import Data.Typeable

applyIf :: (Show a, Typeable a, Show b, Typeable b) => (b -> b) -> a -> String
applyIf f x = case cast x of
    Nothing -> show x
    Just y  -> show (f y)

main = do
  putStrLn $ applyIf ((*2) :: Int -> Int) (1 :: Int)
  putStrLn $ applyIf ((*2) :: Int -> Int) "ok"
```

Here we use `Typeable` to check at runtime whether `a` and `b` are the same type, which either lets us apply `f` or not.

Answer (score 3):

> Proxy is a type that **holds no data**, but has a phantom parameter of arbitrary type (or even kind).

I.e. at runtime you can't tell if you have a `Proxy Int` and so can't pattern match on this. Instead of `Proxy` you need [`TypeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Type.Reflection

class ApplyIf a where
  applyIf :: Show b => TypeRep a -> (a -> a) -> b -> String

instance ApplyIf Int where
  applyIf tr f b | tr == typeRep @Int = show (f b)
                 | otherwise = show b
```

(you need `TypeApplications` for `@Int`). You could use `typeOf (0 :: Int)` as well.

EDIT: would this do what you want? See [`Data.Type.Equality`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Type.Reflection
import Data.Type.Equality

-- could have Typeable a constraint instead of a TypeRep a param
applyIf :: (Show b, Show c, Typeable b) => TypeRep a -> (a -> c) -> b -> String
applyIf tr f b = 
  case testEquality tr (typeOf b) of
    Just Refl -> show (f b)
    Nothing -> show b  

main = do
  putStrLn $ applyIf (typeRep @Int) (*2) 1    -- 2
  putStrLn $ applyIf (typeRep @Int) (*2) "ok" -- ok
```

Comment: Just like in the OP, the `otherwise` case is unreachable, which is why I'm wondering what was really intended.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that at first. My guess is `instance ApplyIf a`, but that wouldn't make the last line make sense.

Comment: I've now replace (a->b) by (a->a).  Still, your code does not compile because TypeRep has kind '\*', not '\* -> \*'.

Comment: @user474491 What is your GHC version? (and `f b` now tries to apply `a -> a` to `b`).

Comment: Ah, I need to import Type.Reflection, not Data.Typeable.

Comment: You can use `Data.Typeable` as well, but the code would be slightly different.

Comment: I now get the error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘b’ on line 8, in the first argument of f...

Comment: That's probably the "(and `f b` now tries to apply `a -> a` to `b`)" I mentioned above (after `a ~ Int` is taken into account).

Comment: So, what's the solution ? how can I make "main" in the original question work ?

Comment: I've tried to show something that should makes it work, but with no `ApplyIf` class (can't test on this machine).

Comment: Though now I see melpomene's answer, and it's a simpler implementation.